# Process.Kill() and process events

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, process

Here is the situation:
I have to create a program that would input another processes output stream into textbox. That it self wouldn't cause too much problem. What does, however, is the fact that I have to run 5 instances of this console application and redirect output to 5 textboxes, as well as to be able to kill any of these processes at any time. As far as I have learned, the best way to do this is asynchronously. But the problem here is with killing processes, that are created on different thread. How do I kill it without having access to it since it doesn't exist in scope where I have to kill it. My best guess is to get its PID on `Process.Start()`, so I can kill it, so...

Is it possible to fire any event from process on `Process.kill()` command?
And if not - is there a way to kill a process in about the same time interval as `Process.Kill()` that does fire some sort of event?

Or maybe someone could suggest me some other approaches or best practice on how these problems are usually solved?

EDIT: The reason I am running all processes on different threads is that I use `Thread.Sleep()` on some of them if there is and input parameter that tell me that the process must be killed after x seconds.

Comment: You said: "But the problem here is with killing processes, that are created on different thread." A process is not created on a different thread. A process is a process. Are you mixing up process and thread?

Comment: @PVitt i think he's talking about Process Object ,so best approach could be to store a Static List<> with Process Name and Process ID where you can get Process ID and kill it !

Comment: But can process name and ID can even be assigned on start info? Isn't OS the one that assigns those? Also process names are all the same since I am running just 5 instances of the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Kill() command for some reason, does, in fact, fire process exited event. Easiest way for me to know that the process was killed, was by making a volatile string that holds information about how it ended. (Change it to "killed" before process.kill etc...)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need Threads at all. Starting a process is async in itself, so Process.Start(...) does not block and you can create as many processes as you want.

Instead of using the static Process.Start method you should consider creating Process class instances and set the CanRaiseEvents property to true. Further there are a couple of events you can register (per instance) - those will only raise if CanRaiseEvents is set to true, but also after a process is/has exited (including Kill() calls).

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
Process.Start()
```

it returns a Process class instance, which you can use to retrieve information from it output and kill that process any time

```
Process p = Process.Start("process.exe");
//some operations with process, may be in another thread
p.Kill()
```